# Executing stored procedure with IN and OUT parameters in PHP

Tags: php, sql-server, php-mssql

I want to execute a stored procedure into my PHP code, this stored procedure has an IN and an OUT parameter. The stored procedure is this:

```
    USE [phl_pmx]

GO

DECLARE @return_value int

EXEC    @return_value = [dbo].[PMX_SP_RecreateSynonymsOfSourceDb]

                    @sourceDb = phl

SELECT  'Return Value' = @return_value

GO
```

And I already wrote the following code, but it keeps giving errors that he can't execute it, or he just won't show a thing.

```
    <?php
ini_set('display_errors',1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include_once 'DBC.php';
$link = mssql_connect('server', 'sa', 'password');

if (isset($_POST['StoredProcedure']))
{

mssql_select_db($id,$link);


$a = new TableOutput();
$a->getTables ("PMX_SP_RecreateSynonymsOfSourceDb","phl");

mssql_close($link);



}
elseif (isset($_POST['Value']))
{
$query =mssql_query("UPDATE [phl].[dbo].[PMX_EXDB] set ExtraDb='phl_pmx'");
mssql_close($link); 
}

?>
```

This is the function for it.

```
<?php
class TableOutput {

function getTables($procname, $parameter) {

    $stmt = null;
    $data = null;
    $vars = null;
    $num = null;
     $con = mssql_connect('server', 'sa', 'password');
if
    (!$con) {
        die('Could not connect: ' . mssql_error());
    }

    mssql_select_db("phl",$con);  

    $this->setStmt(mssql_init($procname, $con));
    mssql_bind($this->getStmt(), '@sourceDb', $parameter, SQLINT2, false, false);

    if ($rtn != 0) {
        echo ("Errors happened when executing the stored procedure");
    }
    $exec = mssql_execute($this->getStmt());
    $data = array();
    $i = 0;
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_assoc($exec)) {
        $data[++$i] = $row;
    }

    unset($con);
    unset($stmt);
    return $data;
}

function setStmt($a_stmt) {
    $this->stmt = $a_stmt;
}

function getStmt() {
    return $this->stmt;
}

}
?>`
```

Does anyone know how to correct the code, because it keeps showing me the following error:

`Warning: mssql_execute(): stored procedure execution failed in /var/www/mssql/management/DBC.php on line 24 Warning: mssql_fetch_assoc() expects parameter 1 to be resource, boolean given in /var/www/mssql/management/DBC.php on line 27`

Answer (score 0):

I don't know MSSQL stored procedures, so I can't analyse your stored procedure. If your proc is returning multiple resultsets you need to use [mssql_next_result](http://www.php.net/manual/de/function.mssql-next-result.php):

```
do {
    while ($row = mssql_fetch_row($exec)) {
        $data[++$i] = $row;
    }
} while (mssql_next_result($exec));
```

Maybe this helps.